# Change eclipse theme to dark, but keep the default error highlight

Tags: eclipse

So, basically, whenever I switch the Eclipse theme to "Dark", it also changes the way that eclipse highlights errors by replacing the standard red squiggle line with an atrocious red background, making it nearly impossible to see anything inside of it.

How, if possible, can I change the error highlight back to the squiggle?

Comment: The yellow warnings can be a problem too, though less severe. Hopefully, an answer is forthcoming on this.